# Using CursorLoader W/ Local Database

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Quick general question regarding the proper use of CursorLoaders.
Here is my example: Within one of my Activities, I query a local database through a ContentProvider for a specific row of data. I currently am instantiating the Cursor object in my onCreate method as such:

```
    String[] projection = {COLUMN_DAY_OF_WEEK, COLUMN_DATE};
    Uri weatherQueryUri = BlahBlah.WeatherData.CONTENT_URI;
    weatherQueryUri = weatherQueryUri.buildUpon().appendPath(weatherID).build();
    String selectionWhere = WeatherContract.WeatherData._ID + "=?";
    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(weatherQueryUri,projection,selectionWhere,new String[]{weatherID},null);
```

My question is, is it better practice to implement a CursorLoader and perform this task on a background thread? I use Loaders when retrieving data from servers all of the time but am now wondering it if makes sense to use this same approach when dealing a local SQLite database? Can someone explain why or why not or does it not really matter? Thank you.

Comment: question is primarily opinion-based ... anyway I would use (and I'm using) CursorLoader even if `getContentResolver().query` would be realy quick

Comment: @Selvin Missed you man! Glad to see you're stealing wheeling and dealing on Stack. Keep killin it. Thanks for the response.